# How to get invoice payload?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

While making an invoice with python-telegram-bot I pass an invoice payload to it. I can then get it in PreCheckoutQueryHandler, but how can I get it in the handler with the SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT filter? python-telegram-bot v20.4

First, after processing payment comes this handler, where I can do query.invoice_payload to get it.

```
application.add_handler(PreCheckoutQueryHandler(precheckout_callback))
```

How can I do this with this handler:

```
application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT, successful_payment_callback))
```

Comment: You get passed a SuccessfulPayment object, right?  That includes the invoice.  https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.successfulpayment.html